# Bot Framework state management using rest service

Tags: c#, botframework

In the documentation for state management, it is mentioned that we can use rest service for state management, instead of overriding the `IBotDataStore`.

Can someone provide the method to do the same.

I have a database, which is not directly accessible from the bot code.So, I am planning to build a webservice for the database and store the state inside the db.

Comment: Good question. I just removed the [tag:sql] tag as this question is generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of the framework, the main point is to create a class that implement `IBotDataStore<BotData>`, and then register your class like they do for `TableBotDataStore` or `SqlBotDataStore`.

The `IBotDataStore<BotData>` interface is defined in BotBuilder's GitHub project, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/BotData.cs).

With this interface, you will have to implement a few methods:

- `Task<T> LoadAsync(IAddress key, BotStoreType botStoreType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` in order to get your data
- `Task SaveAsync(IAddress key, BotStoreType botStoreType, T data, CancellationToken cancellationToken);` in order to save your data
- `Task<bool> FlushAsync(IAddress key, CancellationToken cancellationToken);` in order to flush your data

It's inside those methods that your REST API calls will take place.

You can have a look to how it is made for Azure storages in BotBuilder-Azure GitHub's project, for example for `TableBotDataStore`, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableBotDataStore.cs)